# Get detailed explanation for invalid SSL certificate (.NET)

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient

My service does health pings to customer web sites and reports their health. One of common issues of web site being down is being something wrong with SSL certificate.

In [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback) it is possible to get access to certificates, chain, etc. and to do manual checks (when SslPolicyErrors is not None).

I wonder whether there is a library/method which gives explanation what's wrong (for instance, certificate is expired or root certificate is untrusted, etc.)

Comment: You can get some idea from SSL Diagnostics, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/v13.0.0.8/JexusManager/Features/Main/SslDiagDialog.cs#L188

Comment: BTW, as you are using `HttpClient` you should construct it by using your own `HttpClientHandler` and then set a per instance handler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.8 `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is a global one which affects too many things.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. Yes, I'm using the one on WebRequestHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [X509Chain class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain) can provide a detailed explanation why some certificate is considered invalid.

```
  var errors = new List<string>();
  var chain = new X509Chain();
  // certificate is the one you want to check
  chain.Build(certificate);

  // traverse certificate chain
  foreach (var chainElement in chain.ChainElements)
  {
    // ChainElementStatus contains validation errors
    foreach (var status in chainElement.ChainElementStatus)
    {
      errors.Add(status.Status + " " + chainElement.Certificate + ": " + status.StatusInformation.Trim());
    }
  }
```

This is similar to what [X509Certificate2.Verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify) does (if you look into the source code), albeit Verify only returns true or false.

Comment: Works like a charm! Exactly what I needed. Thank you!